# Decoding GS1-128 UCC/EAN128 with Motorola EMDK 2.6

Tags: barcode, motorola, motorola-emdk, gs1-128

I want to decode a GS1-128 (form. ECC/EAN128) barcode with the Motorola emdk Version 2.6. I use the ES400 as Test-Device. I only get the data in native text format.

For example `(01)25416898545645(17)080600(30)0306180021` returns `012541689854564517080600300306180021`.

I did not get the FNC1 (ascii102)  or GS (ascii 29) Character. I tried the "RawData" with no Result.

How I can handle this?

Answer (score 7):

The 'missing' FNC1s are not present by design. The spec (GS1 General specifications) states that FNC1s in the first position shall not be represented in the transmitted message.

Also, FNC1s are not required after fixed-length Application Identifiers, and after the last AI in a barcode. Your AI's 01 and 17 are defined with datalength 14 and 6. AI 30 is variable length, but also the last element in the barcode, so no FNC1 required.

So to decode the GS1-128: (read the AI, if the length is defined as fixed, read x characters. If it's variable length, read until FNC1 or end of the barcode) repeat until end of barcode.

Answer (score 3):

Fisrt FNC1 is not supossed to be decoded as ascii102, but "]C1". Take a look at [AIM Symbology Identifiers](http://www.morovia.com/education/aim-si.asp).

Next FNC1s are supossed to be decoded as `<GS>` but it's probable you can't see them. Try to scan them in a text editor, save it and load it in a text editor like Scite where you can see control characters.

You can configure Motorola's DataWedge to show the AIM Symbology Identifier, and to map `<GS>` to a common character, like `$` or `=`.

Comment: You've got me on the right track. I have to set the "CodeIDType" in the Barcode2-Class.
myBarcode2.Config.Scanner.CodeIdType = CodeIdTypes.AIM;
Now the FNC-Char was reported as" ]C". Thanks!